# Firebase vs Google Cloud Storage (GCS) for static websites

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am planning to host a React-based web application which has static assets (JS, CSS and Images) on GCP. I am looking for Google Cloud Storage vs Firebase.

Any suggestions? Which 1 to choose? Why?

Comment: This is quite a bit broader a question than SO normally handles and may well get closed. I'd recommend asking this type of question on reddit. Specifically r/googlecloud is a great place to ask this sort of question with lots of users that have strong opinions.

Comment: Having said that, I'm more of a fan of Firebase personally as https is a lot simpler to setup on Firebase hosting than GCS hosting. GCS involves a number of steps to serve HTTPS (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#https) while Firebase is a checkbox basically.